# Android: Tabbed actionbar in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I am unsure what to search for this so all links are appreciated.

When I change the orientation of my device to portrait mode all the tabs are going below the action bar, not on it, even though there is plenty of room (I am using 2 tabs while testing on a Nexus 10). Will the tabs always appear below the action bar in portrait mode or is there a way around this?

What I want to happen:

[image: Valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [android.com](https://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-tabs@2x.png))</sub>

What is happening: **NOTE: this is the behavior I am getting even when there is PLENTY of room to display the tabs in the action bar**:

[image: Valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [android.com](https://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-tabs-stacked@2x.png))</sub>

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "New ActionBar policy for embedded tabs: embedded tabs are now always stacked in the action bar when in portrait mode, regardless of the size of the screen."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#JELLY_BEAN

Found it from this post: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/655

Comment: @DaiwikDaarun have you solved the problem, I have the same issue with you.

Comment: I ended up moving to [SlidingTabLayout instead](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html).  Its a really popular open source tab with lots of info on the web!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the tabs always appear below the action bar in portrait mode

On small/normal screens, yes. Action bar tabs will go where the action bar implementation wants to put them... which includes them not being tabs at all in some cases, but a drop-down list instead.